# Eclipse and Kies don't find my mobile, but ADB does

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, adb

I have been looking all over this place after some answers but with no luck. My problem is not like the others where the device doesn't even show up when you type:

```
adb devices
```

When I type that command in my terminal I get this:

```
List of devices attached 
4df1162756ad7f0f    device
```

But Eclipse doesn't find anything, and yes I have the checked the USB-debug, and every single solution on the web...

But something I think is suspicious is that ADB has no problem finding my device, and that seems to be a problem to everybody else.

If somebody has a clue what my problem is, please help me.

BTW, I'm running Mac Mountain Lion and a Samsung S3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Occassionally, selecting the adb-reset button within eclipse from the drop-down in the DDMS window will do the trick, but you still need to unplug and replug the device in at that point.

Additionally, you can manually do it through the command line with adb kill-server and adb start-server.

Occassionally a reset of the physical device or a reset of the computer itself is necessary as well.  But, we can assume that you have all the plugins added into your Eclipse, so it shouldn't be a problem such as that; I have an S4 and don't recall doing anything else on the Mac here to get it going other than that.

Comment: I think that was the magic thing! It's works now :) After weeks i can finally debugg my apps without that emulator :P

Answer (score 0):

Try [ADB Driver Installer](http://adbdriver.com/). It detects and install drivers for majority of android devices.